# Bring cells content or reference where my search is true

Tags: excel, vba

How can I bring the content of the cells (or just their reference) for which the statement below is true?

```
 =+AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B12,A:A)),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C12,A:A))),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D12,A:A))),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E12,A:A))))
```

What I do with this formula, is search if multiple values are in one of A:A cells.
If that´s true, I need to know where.

Comment: So (for example) if A34 contained the text from B12 AND the the text from C12 AND the the text from D12 AND the text from E12 then show the text in A34? If A39 had the same matches then show A39 under the text from A34?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a 4 criteria match in a lookup. This shouldn't be much harder than taking a standard two criteria lookup formula nd adding a couple more matches to it.

[image: Four criteria match in INDEX]

The standard formula in F12 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9999, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9999)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$12, $A$1:$A$9999))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$12, $A$1:$A$9999))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$12, $A$1:$A$9999))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$12, $A$1:$A$9999))), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill down until you run out of matches. If you just want the row number then the standard formula in G12 would be,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9999)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$12, $A$1:$A$9999))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$12, $A$1:$A$9999))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$12, $A$1:$A$9999))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$12, $A$1:$A$9999))), ROW(1:1))
```

Again, fill down as necessary.

Comment: That's closer but still not there. If I've my words let's say in B1,C1,D1, I  need to bring to E1...Z1, the values of those cells from column A that includes B1,C1,D1-if any.  I can't use cells from row 2, because B2,C2,D2, have their own values to be researched. Do you know if this solution could be adapted for this restriction? By the way,  your cocker looks like mine, but a bit more serious!